# Gstreamer copy data from one pipeline to another

Tags: c, gstreamer

**Background**: I have an app which takes a pipeline from an USB camera and saves the video output to a file. Now I want to to do that but work with the frames in the application. So I have following code, so during testing I have main pipeline from the camrea to the filesink and appsink (using tee), and secondary from appsource (at this point basically the previously mentioned appsink) to different filesink.  So i have:

1. Pipeline one: camera------>tee--------->filesink1
   tee--------->appsink
2. Pipeline two: (appsink->)appsource------>filesink2

**Goal**: do not use the tee in the first pipeline, but copy (and later perform something on the -) each sample from the first pipeline reduced to camera--->appsink to the second pipeline.

1. Pipeline one: camera------>appsink
2. Pipeline two: (appsink->some work->)appsource------>filesink

**Problem**: Both testing videos are created, both have equal size. But the one created from appsrc->filesink pipeline claim to have 0s lenght, no matter how long the video actually is. anyone can guess why?
**Code:**

```cpp
    GstElement *pipeline_main; //main pipeline FROM the camera
    GstElement *pipeline_saveVideo;
    GstElement *tee; //splitter
    GstCaps *caps; //caps currently set to the camera
    GstElement *videoApssrc; //source for the pipeline to SAVE the video;
    bool record;

static GstFlowReturn new_sample_jpeg(GstElement * elt)
{
    GstSample *sample;
    GstFlowReturn ret = GST_FLOW_OK;

    // get the sample from appsink
    sample = gst_app_sink_pull_sample (GST_APP_SINK (elt));
    //if recording, send the sample to recording sink
    if (record) gst_app_src_push_sample(GST_APP_SRC(videoApssrc), sample);
...
    return ret;
}
bool createPipelineVideo(std::string path){

     GstStateChangeReturn ret;
     GstElement  *muxer, *sink, *queue;
     videoApssrc = gst_element_factory_make ("appsrc", "saveVideoSource");

     muxer = gst_element_factory_make ("avimux", "avimux");
     queue = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "rcr_queue");
     sink = gst_element_factory_make ("filesink", "sink");
     g_object_set (sink, "location", path().c_str(), NULL);

     pipeline_saveVideo = gst_pipeline_new ("pipeline_vid");

     if (!pipeline_saveVideo || !videoApssrc || !muxer || !sink) {
       g_printerr ("Not all elements could be created.\n");
       return false;
     }
     gst_app_src_set_caps(GST_APP_SRC(videoApssrc), caps);
     gst_app_src_set_duration(GST_APP_SRC(videoApssrc), GST_TIME_AS_MSECONDS(80));
     gst_app_src_set_stream_type(GST_APP_SRC(videoApssrc), GST_APP_STREAM_TYPE_STREAM);
     gst_app_src_set_latency(GST_APP_SRC(videoApssrc), -1, 0);

     gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline_saveVideo), videoApssrc,queue,  sink, NULL);
     if (gst_element_link_many(videoApssrc, queue, sink, NULL) != TRUE) {
       g_printerr ("Elements could not be linked.\n");
       gst_object_unref (pipeline_saveVideo);
       return false;
     }

     ret = gst_element_set_state (pipeline_saveVideo, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
     if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
       g_printerr ("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
       gst_object_unref (pipeline_saveVideo);
       return false;
     }
    return true;
}

void startCapturing(){
    if (!gst_is_initialized()) {
        qWarning()<<"initializing GST";
        setenv("GST_DEBUG", ("*:" + std::to_string(3)).c_str(), 1);
        gst_init(nullptr, nullptr);
    }
    GstStateChangeReturn ret;
    GstElement *source, *muxer, *sink, *queue_rcr, *queue_app, *appsink;
    source = gst_element_factory_make ("v4l2src", "source");
    g_object_set (source, "device", "/dev/video1", NULL);

    muxer = gst_element_factory_make ("avimux", "avimux");
    tee = gst_element_factory_make("tee", "tee");
    sink = gst_element_factory_make ("filesink", "sink");
    queue_rcr = gst_element_factory_make ("queue", "record_queue");
    queue_app = gst_element_factory_make ("queue", "app_queue");

    appsink = gst_element_factory_make("appsink", "appsink");
    g_object_set (sink, "location", "/mnt/test1.avi", NULL);

    pipeline_main = gst_pipeline_new ("pipeline_src");

    if (!pipeline_main || !source || !muxer || !sink || !queue_rcr || !appsink) {
      g_printerr ("Not all elements could be created.\n");
      return;
    }
    caps = gst_caps_new_simple ("image/jpeg",
                 "width", G_TYPE_INT, 1920,
                 "height", G_TYPE_INT, 1080,
                 "io-mode", G_TYPE_INT, 4,
                 "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 30, 1,
                 "pixel-aspect-ratio", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 1,1,
                 "interlace-mode", G_TYPE_STRING, "progresive",
                 NULL);


    gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline_main), source, muxer,tee, sink,queue_rcr, appsink, queue_app, NULL);
    if (gst_element_link_filtered(source, tee, caps) != TRUE) {
      gstFail("Elements could not be linked or caps set.\n");
      return;
    }
    if (gst_element_link_many(tee, queue_rcr, muxer, sink, NULL) != TRUE) {
        gstFail("Elements could not be linked-recording line\n");
        return;
    }
    if (gst_element_link_many(tee, queue_app, appsink, NULL) != TRUE) {
        gstFail("Elements could not be linked-recording line\n");
        return;
    }
    gst_app_sink_set_emit_signals(GST_APP_SINK(appsink), true);
    g_signal_connect (appsink, "new-sample", G_CALLBACK (new_sample_jpeg));
    ret = gst_element_set_state (pipeline_main, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

    if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
      gstFail("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
      return;
    }

    // Start playing
    createPipelineVideo("/mnt/test2.avi");

    record = true;

   return;
}

void endVideo(){
    record = false;
    GstMessage *message = gst_message_new_eos(nullptr);
    /* Free resources */
    if (message != NULL)
      gst_message_unref (message);
    gst_element_set_state (pipeline_main, GST_STATE_PAUSED);
    gst_element_set_state (pipeline_main, GST_STATE_NULL);
    sleep(1);
    gst_object_unref (pipeline_main);

    //push the image in the pipeline
    GstMessage *EndMessage = gst_message_new_eos(&pipeline_saveVideo->object);
    gst_bus_post(pipeline_saveVideo->bus, EndMessage);
    /* Free resources */
    if (message != NULL)
      gst_message_unref (EndMessage);
    GstFlowReturn status = GstFlowReturn::GST_FLOW_OK;
    status = gst_app_src_end_of_stream(GST_APP_SRC(videoApssrc));
    //end the pipeline
    usleep(500000);
    gst_element_set_state (pipeline_saveVideo, GST_STATE_PAUSED);
    gst_element_set_state (pipeline_saveVideo, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref (pipeline_saveVideo);
}
```

Comment: 0 length on file sinks usually comes from missing EOS signal. Tee element forwards EOS signal to all its pads, but app sink does not.

On this design you might have to listen to first pipeline EOS and emit it on second one manually. Check https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/app/appsink.html#appsink::eos

Comment: thanks for the response. However, I do have ```cpp     status = gst_app_src_end_of_stream(GST_APP_SRC(videoApssrc));
``` line in the "endVideo" function. I believe that should take care of this.